# @videogular/ngx-videogular make the video autoPlay the moment the component is loaded

Tags: angular

I'm using the package @videogular/ngx-videogular for the video player in my app.
Unfortunately, I'm not able to make the video play the moment that the component loaded (only by hitting the play button).

**html.**

```
    <section class="video" (onPlayerReady)="onPlayerReady($event)">
  <vg-player>
      <vg-controls>
          <vg-play-pause></vg-play-pause>
      </vg-controls>
      <video #media [vgMedia]="$any(media)" preload="auto" autoplay="true" crossorigin src="{{contentResponse?.data?.videoUrl}}">
          Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
  </vg-player>
</section>
```

**ts**.

```
  api!: VgApiService



onPlayerReady(api: VgApiService) {
    this.api = api;
    this.api.getDefaultMedia().subscriptions.loadedMetadata.subscribe(
        this.playVideo.bind(this)
      );
  }

  playVideo() {
    this.api.play();
  }
```

The video doest plays on component load.
I have tried searching online about this issue but found nothing. does anyone know how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The Videogular API is based on RxJS, so you can subscribe to Observables and react in consequence. To autoplay the videos, we need to listen for the loadedmetadata event.

Let’s add a new Subscription to play the video when the metadata is loaded:

```
export class AppComponent {
   // ...
 
   onPlayerReady(api: VgAPI) {
       this.api = api;
       this.api.getDefaultMedia().subscriptions.loadedMetadata.subscribe(
           this.playVideo.bind(this)
       );
   }
 
   playVideo() {
      this.api.play();
   }
 
   // ...
}
```

We simply play the video via the VgAPI when the loadedMetadata observable is fired.

Comment: Thanks!!! But could you please explain me what import should i use for VgAPI?

Comment: try: import {VgAPI} from 'videogular2/core'; More info: https://videogular.github.io/videogular2/docs/getting-started/using-the-api.html

Comment: videogular2/core is not the location anymore.

Comment: try import { VgAPI } from 'videogular2/compiled/core';

Comment: The right import is: import { VgApiService } from '@videogular/ngx-videogular/core';

Comment: Great, that will help other users

Comment: Where should i use the onPlayerReady() and playVideo() in the html?

Comment: For example: <vg-player (onPlayerReady)="onPlayerReady($event)">

Comment: Just use onPlayerReady() since he is going to call playVideo()

Comment: Thanks! last question, what about the property api in the ts?
I'm getting this error because the api property isn't initialized
Property 'api' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)

Comment: And im not able to use this solution: "strictPropertyInitialization": false

Comment: I fixed it like this:   api!: VgApiService

Comment: great in which file or part?

Comment: I will edit the question and please look the updated quesiton. unfortunately the video doesn't play

Comment: The post is edited :)

Comment: Maybe it's something from the same angle and not from videogular.